# using throttleTime function on subject angular2 error

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

I'm trying to use throttleTime operator on a subject. I have imported the operator. I'm getting this error: `this.cropSubject.asObservable(...).throttleTime is not a function`. I can't figure out what is going wrong. Is this a bug?

```ts
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { throttleTime } from 'rxjs/operator/throttleTime';


export class EditItemComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit{


    cropSubject: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();


    constructor(private taggingDataService: TaggingDataService, private _elementRef : ElementRef) {
    taggingDataService.selectedTags.subscribe((newTags) => {
        this.selectedTags = newTags;
    })
    this.cropSubject.asObservable().throttleTime(1000).subscribe((croppedImageSrc) => {
        this.updateImageData(croppedImageSrc);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to add the operator. You're just importing the implementation.

```ts
import 'rxjs/add/operator/throttleTime';
```

It will add the `throttleTime` operator to the prototype.

Comment: aahh....this always gets me. I was doing `import { throttleTime } from 'rxjs/operator/throttleTime';`

Comment: yeah... this is just the implementation... you could use it, but it's weird: `throttleTime.call(someObservable, time)`

Comment: If if makes you feel any better, I'm working on a big PR to make this a lot easier for you and everyone else in the near future. (I hope). :D

Comment: @BenLesh Is the work in progress available somewhere? I curious what is it going to look like :).